# Structured binary data compiler/decompiler?

Tags: hex-editors

Is there a hex "editor" out there that handles structured data *and* works as a compiler/decompiler tool?  That is, it can take a text description of structured binary data and turn it into the actual binary data, and the reverse?  For example, (inventing syntax wildly) given the definition `uint16_be = count(myArray); uint16_be myArray[]` and the input `{ 16, 17, 18 }`, you'd get the bytes `00 03 00 10 00 11 00 12`; if you fed those bytes into the reverse tool with the same definition, you'd get the text `{ 16, 17, 18 }`.

To be clear: I want *structured* input and output, not just streams of hex.  `xxd` won't cut it.

Several hex editors have data templates which address the structured binary-to-text problem, but that doesn't let me go the other way, and I want something that works as a command-line tool so I can use it in builds.  If you're an old enough Mac developer, you might remember Rez and DeRez; what I want is basically that, but to operate on plain files.  Any suggestions?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/573570/411376

Comment: `xxd` handles the round-trip to text part, but not the structured part.  I edited the question to make that more clear.